# Solving this differential equation with matlab?

Tags: matlab, math, equation

This would be it :
y'(t)=y(t)/t-t^2/y^2*t 
y(1)=1

i have tried:
function hazi3b()

[T,Y] = ode45( @bfugveny, [1 12], 1);
plot(T, Y, 'gx')

end

and:

function dy=bfugveny(t,y)

dy = y(t)/t - t^2/(y^2*t);

end

Comment: Attempted to access y(1.22); index must be a positive integer or logical.

Error in bfugveny (line 3)
dy = y(t)/t - t^2/(y^2*t);

Error in ode45 (line 262)
    f(:,2) = feval(odeFcn,t+hA(1),y+f*hB(:,1),odeArgs{:});

Error in hazi3b (line 2)
[T,Y] = ode45( @bfugveny, [1 12], 1);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to write `y(t)` in your formula.

The `y` passed into your oracle is already a guess for `y`-evaluated-at-time-`t`.

So try

```
dy = y/t - t^2/(y^2*t);
```

Comment: So accept the answer....gratitude is good, but acceptance is good for you and the person who helped you.  Vote it up, too.